# Repeated catch–mark–release (urn problem)

Tags: r, sampling, population, capture-mark-recapture

Imagine I have a small pond with some fish in it and I want to estimate its population size. I don't have a lot of resources at hand, in fact all I do have is a fishing pole, pen and paper, and a lot of patience.

One morning I sit down at the end of the pier and start fishing. For every fish I pull I examine it for a mark. If it has none I write down a 0 in my note book, give the fish a mark, and release it. If it already has a mark I write down a 1 in my note book and release the fish. I repeat this procedure 40 times and at the end have the following sequence:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1
```

How can I use this data to estimate the population size of the fish in my pond? And compared to a standard [mark–recapture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_and_recapture) procedure where I capture just as many fish, in what ways are my method worse?
I assume ideal conditions, like constant population size and each fish being equally likely to get caught.

So far all I have are the reasonably obvious. The probability of capturing a marked fish increase every time I capture a non-marked fish, which sounds a bit like a poisson process (no pun intended).

My problem seems also to be similar to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2466/estimate-the-size-of-a-population-being-sampled-by-the-number-of-repeat-observat?rq=1) question, but different enough for me not to know what to do about it.

For any fellow `R` fiends and others interested, the above sequence was generated like this:

```
set.seed(1)
pool <- rep(0, 64)
capture <- vector()

for (i in 1:40) {
capture[i] <- sample(pool, 1)
if (capture[i]==0) pool <- c(pool[-1], 1)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_i=1$ denote the event that the $i$'th fish caught is already marked and $x_i=0$ the event that you catch a new fish which you then mark.  Prior to catch $i$, the number of fish marked (the cumulative number of zeros in your sequence) is 
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} (1-x_j)=i-1-\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}x_j.
$$
Hence, letting $N$ denote the unknown population size, the probability mass function of $x_i$ conditional on past observation is
$$
p(x_i|x_1,\dots,x_{i-1}) = f(x_i,\frac{i-1-\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}x_j}N)
$$
where $f(x,p)$ is the probability mass function of a Bernoulli variable with parameter $p$ (`dbinom(  )` in the code below).  By the probability chain rule, the total likelihood is
$$
L(N) = p(x_1,\dots,x_n)=p(x_1)p(x_2|x_1)\cdots p(x_n|x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}).
$$
The following R code implements this and produces the plot below.

```
loglikelihood <- function(N,x) {
  n <- length(x) 
  i <- 1:n
  marked <- i - 1 - c(0,cumsum(x))[-n]
  sum(dbinom(x, size=1, prob=marked/N, log=TRUE))
}
NN <- 1:300
ll <- vector()
for (i in 1:length(NN)) 
  ll[i] <- loglikelihood(NN[i],x=capture)
plot(NN,exp(ll),type="l",ylab="Likelihood",xlab="Population size N")
```

[image]

Comment: I've had to revisit some old lecture notes on Maximum Likelihood and read about the [Coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) for some context, but I think I'm slowly getting my head around this.